# NoClassDefFoundError in 4.4 kitkat but not in 5.0 Lollipop - Could not find class

Tags: java, android, quickblox, image-load, q-municate

have an error in my application but I can not find it. Android 5.0 works normally, but in 4.4 of this error below:

> Could not find class
>   'com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.ImageUtils$SmartUriDecoder',
>   referenced from method
>   com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.ImageUtils.getImageLoaderConfiguration

Shortly after it appears:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.ImageUtils$SmartUriDecoder
>   at
>   com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.ImageUtils.getImageLoaderConfiguration(ImageUtils.java:67)
>   at com.quickblox.q_municate.App.initImageLoader(App.java:32)
>   at com.quickblox.q_municate.App.initApplication(App.java:42)
>   at com.quickblox.q_municate.App.onCreate(App.java:27)

Does anyone know what can it be?

Comment: does that class exist in 4.4  ?

Comment: @StackFlowed I don't understand your question!

Comment: does this com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.ImageUtils exist in 4.4 ? was this introduced in 5.0 ? is the location is the some ?

Comment: @StackFlowed i dont think that ImageUtils is from android SDK.
CleidimarViana is it possible to post the content of com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.ImageUtils ?

Comment: @user3162662 Content on this  [ https://www.dropbox.com/s/w1xkoybp086hu2o/ImageUtils.java?dl=0 ] (link)

Comment: @user3162662 Please help me! :(

Comment: @StackFlowed The project worked with before 4.4, but when I pass the set to 5.0, just stopped working in 4.4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947081/android-studio-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing,

```
multiDexEnabled = false
```

in your `build.gradle` file.

If you already have `multiDexEnabled = true` then change it to `false` or add this new line.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have the correct libraries imported in your project and go to your gradle to make sure that you're compiling everything that you're trying to use.

Comment: Yeah man, I'm compiling. However, the design works in 5.0 but not at 4.4. This is weird.