# Could not find class/NoClassDefFound error on Android running 4.3/ pre L

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception, android-4.4-kitkat, android-multidex

I have an android application that seems to run fine on Android L+ devices. However, when I try to run it for pre L devices, I seem to get an exception on `Could not Find Class` or `NoClassDefFoundError` and these classes seem to be from a different project on which my project is dependent upon.

I tried [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android devices with KitKat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914217/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-on-android-devices-with-kitkat) and [NoClassDefFoundError in 4.4 kitkat but not in 5.0 Lollipop - Could not find class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072826/noclassdeffounderror-in-4-4-kitkat-but-not-in-5-0-lollipop-could-not-find-clas) , which recommended me to disable `multidex` in build.gradle, but it did not find the issue and I started getting `transformClasseswithDexforDebug` errors listed at [UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798816/unexpected-top-level-exception-com-android-dex-dexexception-multiple-dex-files), which recommended me to turn back `multiDex` back to enabled.

Here is a sample stacktrace of the errror:

`01-28 17:09:21.214 15125-15125/<app> I/dalvikvm: Could not find method <XXX>, referenced from method <YYY>.findZygotePid
01-28 17:09:21.190 15125-15125/<app> E/dalvikvm: Could not find class '<ZZZ>', referenced from method <AAA>.broadcast
01-28 17:09:21.229 15125-15125/<AAA> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                             java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <Method from a dependent project's class>`

Both my main Android project and the dependent module have multidex enabled and dependencies is set to compile `com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0`. Can someone please provide some inputs on how do I go about fixing the exception being thrown on pre L devices? Any inputs would be appreciated.

I also tried clean build and rebuild of the project, but it doesn't help me. Thanks.

UPDATE: Sample Code

```
class Dummy { 
Dummy(<params>) {
        initialize variables;
    }

}
```

and this is being invoked as `new Dummy(<params>)`, where it throws an exception of `NoClassDefFound` package_name.Dummy

Comment: there are some api's in lollipop which requires minimum sdk version to be lollipop. So those classes wouldn't be available in pre lollipop devices, therefore you get that error

Comment: It is just a timer task, who reference is not found, and not some specific Android API, resulting in an exception.

Comment: can you post the code also

Comment: added some dummy code for the reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the above problem, by making my base activity extend `MultiDexApplication` (not `Application`) and the application does not crash now. Also, modified `build.gradle` and `AndroidManifest.xml` to set `minSdkVersion` to 18.

Comment: whaaaat?! are u kidding?! how it can be an activity then?!